# iOS ANCS notifications to Android via BLE

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

As a proof of concept, I would like to write an Android application which can receive notifications (e.g. SMS, Calendar, etc) from an iPhone 5 through the Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS) over Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). The Android device is running Kit Kat 4.4 so this seems possible, since it also supports BLE. However, from what I understand, there is a bug in Android which prevents it from properly communicating with iOS over BLE: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58725

I am a reasonably new Android developer (having spent most of my time in iOS) so I was hoping if someone could provide advice as to whether this bug would be a show-stopper at the moment? If not, any advice on how to approach coding this proof of concept (from both the iOS and Android requirements) would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I understand, this is a showstopper for establishing BLE GATT connections to a number of different stacks (iOS being one of them) and there are no released versions of Android that address it. Nor do I know of any patches in the wild that address it.

If you know something I don't, please respond and let us know? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, were u able to make this app? I am also working on same, so wanted the direction to move forward

Answer (score 2):

On the iOS side, you don't need to do anything at all, since ANCS is running all the time (as long as Bluetooth is enabled) and it is ready to communicate with a client. On the Android side, you would need to use the android.bluetooth package to connect to a device and then subscribe to the appropriate Bluetooth services on the iOS device. This handshake dance is somewhat tricky, but you're essentially subscribing to GATT attributes on the iOS device, from Android, and listening for "notifications" on those attributes. Then you can optionally request more detailed information on each notification that you receive. It requires a basic understanding of Bluetooth/GATT services, plus a fairly intimate understanding of ANCS' particular requirements.

The Apple spec for ANCS is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html

Feel free to clarify the question further if you need more info on the ANCS dance; I've been working with it over the last couple of months. If you've made progress since asking this question, please update us.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting with two sample applications:

1. AHA NP https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/aha-notification-provider/id784772115?mt=8 in the App Store. This will advertise the ANCS Service so you can discover it on your ANCS device
2. Download the Android/iOS bluetooth sample apps from bluetooth.org here: https://developer.bluetooth.org/Pages/Bluetooth-Android-Developers.aspx

Using these two apps you can advertise ANCS from your iOS device and view the ANCS service from your Android device. From there you can modify the android sample app to start reading values from your iPhone.